# Withdraw/delete push notification in React Native

Tags: react-native, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, android-push-notification

Our React Native app needs to send out push notification to a number of people (iOS and Android, app can be open, backgrounded, or closed), and when just one of these people performs a specific in-app action, we need our server to erase these push notifications from everyone's phones (again from either open, backgrounded, or closed). Is this possible to do for both iOS and Android?

Answer (score -1):

You can send background notification (data notification if firebase) and implement frontend listeners to cancel all notifications received so far.